# how to sign request in JMeter?

Tags: ruby, time, jmeter, performance-testing

For individual calls I have a ruby code like that to generate an API request:

```
api_key = 'some-key-here'
shared_secret = 'very-secretive-secret'

timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
sig = Digest::MD5.hexdigest( api_key+shared_secret+timestamp )

request_url = "#{production_point}/#{request}?apikey=#{api_key}&sig=#{sig}&format=json"
puts request_url
```

but that generated request_url will work only for a relatively short time being dependent on current timestamp.

Now I need to do some performance testing, and in JMeter I used to use a file with a list of URL/requests/keywords I need to bang the server with, but those were – with static URLs. Now I need to test a service which requires each request to be signed the way described above, and I can't just use a list.

I understand there is an md5 function available in JMeter. But where do I put the api_key and shared_secret (secret is not a part of URL by itself).

Could someone, please, walk me through setting up JMeter test for a service requiring signing each request with an md5-ed signature requiring a timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of "Beanshell" Test Elements, i.e. [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) in order to generate correct signature value right before the request.

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request which does that API call
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area (it's basically Beanshell equivalent of your Ruby script)

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

   String api_key = "some-key-here";
   String shared_secret = "very-secretive-secret";
   long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

   String sig = DigestUtils.md5Hex(api_key + shared_secret + timestamp);

   vars.put("sig", sig);

   log.info("Signature: " + sig);
   ```
3. Refer generated signature value as `${sig}` where required as it has been stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Demo:
[image: Beanshell MD5]

References:

- [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) (aka `vars`)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: Dmitry, could you, please, show a screenshot of how that variable "sig" referred in the HTTP Request (=one level above the BeanShell PreProcessor)? Do I need to create a variable with no value there? Or HTTP Request gets the "sig" variable from the child automatically, and it just could be used in the URL without any additional efforts?

Comment: Is the DigestUtils deprecated? This no longer seems to be working?